# Azure SSL and TrafficManger Implementation

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-traffic-manager

I have Requirement where i want to configure Azure Traffic Manager with SSL. 
I have Scenarion like I have Hosted WebAPP1.azurewebsite.ne and WebAPP2.azurewebsite.net and configured trafficmanager top of that lets say mytrafficmanager.trafficmanager.net. now i want to buy the SSL Certificate. so please can anybody help me using which name i have to buy the certificate. and how to configured that in

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question where you want to use SSL protection. Could you clarify if it for the health probes originating from Azure Traffic Manager or whether it is for another scenario?

Thanks,
Dilip L [MSFT]